# In CockroachDB, how do I figure out how much memory a query is using?

Tags: cockroachdb

I'm trying to figure out how to attribute memory use in CockroachDB to a particular query. How do I do that? I've tried using `EXPLAIN`, but that doesn't seem to show memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to show the answer to this question. Here's a transcript from [CockroachDB 20.2.2](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/releases/v20.2.2) that shows the method:

```
> ./cockroach-v20.2.2.darwin-10.9-amd64/cockroach demo
# Enter \? for a brief introduction.
#
root@127.0.0.1:64830/demo> create table a (a int primary key, b int);
CREATE TABLE

Time: 3ms total (execution 3ms / network 0ms)

root@127.0.0.1:64830/demo> insert into a select g, 1 from generate_series(1, 10000) g(g);
INSERT 10000

Time: 81ms total (execution 81ms / network 0ms)

root@127.0.0.1:64830/demo> select count(*) from a group by b;
  count
---------
  10000
(1 row)

Time: 7ms total (execution 7ms / network 0ms)

root@127.0.0.1:64830/demo> explain analyze select count(*) from a group by b;
  automatic |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    url
------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    true    | https://cockroachdb.github.io/distsqlplan/decode.html#eJyUkV-Pk0AUxd_9FDf3qTWjO6Cb6DyVXashIlSg0WpIM2VuCAkwODPEbRq-uwHinzVx4z6ec--5c36ZC9pvDQrcft5FQRhDEAfR4csWVm_CLM8-RmvIttH2NodSD51bPV3D2zT5ABLepcl-BzcHOCHDTiuKZUsWxVf0sGDYG12StdpM1mVeCNUdCs6w7vrBTXbBsNSGUFzQ1a4hFJjLU0MpSUXmiiNDRU7WzXxWbnpTt9KckWHWy84KeIYMk8EJ2PjI0OjvFgxJJcDjnE9x62TTgKtbEnD93L9-1VpkeDo7-rn5gvvwvr7BYmSoB_e7mXWyIhTeyP6_fVBVhirptLny7pffTDqID8c4yY_xPopWG2-NDG-TfZwf0-RTtlo_BublL5hW3kFLrTZnGCwpAa_5g0D-Y4BSsr3uLN2D-ddlPhYMSVW0fLnVgylpZ3Q5P7PIZM7NhiLrlqm3iLBbRlPBP8Peg2H_r3AxPvkRAAD__3pr4n4=
(1 row)

Time: 13ms total (execution 13ms / network 0ms)
```

The link shows the following pictures, which contains the memory usage per operator. Notice that the aggregator (the `group by` operator) shows 70 kb, the quantity that we were looking for:

[image: picture of EXPLAIN ANALYZE output]